# Grab firstname from fullname and extract it to a new column with awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have many `.csv` files with customer information. In all these files I want to add an additional column `FIRSTNAME` right next to the column `FULLNAME`. The Firstname can be generated with grabbing the first word from `FULLNAME`.

There are no two-word firstnames like Jean Paul. In the last column a comma is used in the fieldtext

Input

```
COMPANY,FULLNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
Company name,Firstname Lastname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix Lastname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, workhome, work"
Company name,Firstname infix infix2 Lastname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
```

Expected output

```
COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
Company name,Firstname Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix Lastname,Firstname,firstname.infix.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix infix2 Lastname,Firstname,firstname.infix12.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
```

How to do this with awk, sed or something else?

Comment: Can `Company name` contain a comma, e.g., `My Company, LLC`? How about in the other fields? Can we assume valid csv with appropriate quotes?

Comment: @doneal24 updated

Comment: Note that the `COMMENT` field has been modified between the input and expected output, but that you don't mention this in the text. `"home, workhome, work"` in the second record becomes `"home, work"` in the output.

Comment: not all of these apply, but note that as someone with even something mundane and pretty universal as an umlaut in their name, I'd love you to read https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: You state there are no "two-word" first names... are there any "two-word" last names? What might an example of `infix` and/or `infix2` look like?

Comment: @jubilatious1 "van der" in Dutch names, for example, as in "Mathieu van der Poel".

Comment: Even without Kusalananda's "van der" example, how will you prevent simple mistakes from spreading into FIRSTNAME or any other new column or field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the CSV-aware utility [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
mlr --csv \
    put '$FIRSTNAME = sub($FULLNAME," .*","")' then \
    reorder -f COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME file
```

... which, given the data in the question, results in

```
COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
Company name,Firstname Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, workhome, work"
Company name,Firstname infix infix2 Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
```

This use of Miller first creates a new field, `FIRSTNAME`, through a regular expression-based substitution that removes everything after the first space character in the `FULLNAME` field.

Since new fields are presented last, the fields are then reordered to ensure that the first few fields are `COMPANY`, `FULLNAME`, and `FIRSTNAME`, in this order.  The remaining fields are left in their original order.

Instead of the `put` expression using `sub()`, you may use `put` with its `splitnv()` function to split the `FIRSTNAME` field's value on spaces and pick out the 1st generated string:

```bash
mlr --csv \
    put '$FIRSTNAME = splitnv($FULLNAME," ")[1]' then \
    reorder -f COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME file
```

---

For prettier output:

```bash
$ mlr --icsv --opprint --barred put '$FIRSTNAME = splitnv($FULLNAME," ")[1]' then reorder -f COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME file
+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------+
| COMPANY      | FULLNAME                        | FIRSTNAME | EMAIL                          | FUNCTION          | CITY     | INDUSTRY    | COMMENT              |
+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------+
| Company name | Firstname Lastname              | Firstname | firstname.lastname@example.com | Marketing Manager | New York | Health Care | home, work           |
| Company name | Firstname infix Lastname        | Firstname | firstname.lastname@example.com | Marketing Manager | New York | Health Care | home, workhome, work |
| Company name | Firstname infix infix2 Lastname | Firstname | firstname.lastname@example.com | Marketing Manager | New York | Health Care | home, work           |
+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN);  \
                        my @b = [Z] @a>>[0..1], @a>>[1].map(*.words.[0]), @a>>[2..*];  \
                        @b = @b>>.[*;*]>>.Array; @b[0][2] = "FIRSTNAME";  \
                        csv(in => @b, out => $*OUT);'  file
```

This may be the simplest approach, should the OP desire double-quoted CSV output throughout (quoted fields where embedded commas and/or spaces occur, see RFC4180).

The Perl(5) module `Text::CSV_XS` is well-regarded, and a longtime author/maintainer of that module has developed the Raku `Text::CSV` module (H. Merijn Brand, personal communication). Here, Raku's `Text::CSV` functions are confined to IO operations, in particular, the quoted last column. Otherwise, the column manipulations above are done using standard Raku arrays. Still, this code has the advantage that a double-quoted file-path can be used instead of `$*IN`, which takes STDIN.

Above, the file is read-into `@a` array on the first line, in the second line the first `word` of zero-indexed column 1 is taken and assigned to zero-indexed column 2; this and the remainder of the rows are assigned row-by-row to `@b` array. Some housekeeping is done on the third line (flatten array, make `@b` elements mutable, and correct column header). Finally the file is output on the fourth line.

Sample Input:

```
COMPANY,FULLNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
Company name,Firstname Lastname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix Lastname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, workhome, work"
Company name,Firstname infix infix2 Lastname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
```

Sample Output (from above):

```
COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
"Company name","Firstname Lastname",Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,"Marketing Manager","New York","Health Care","home, work"
"Company name","Firstname infix Lastname",Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,"Marketing Manager","New York","Health Care","home, workhome, work"
"Company name","Firstname infix infix2 Lastname",Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,"Marketing Manager","New York","Health Care","home, work"
```

It's actually quite a bit more work to only requote the last column. Replace the last line `csv(in => @b, out => $*OUT)` above with the following:

```
.join(",").put for @b[0];  \
.join(",").put for [Z] @b[1..*]>>.[0..*-2]>>.join(","), @b[1..*]>>.[*-1].map(*.raku);'
```

Sample Output (revised code example):

```
COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
Company name,Firstname Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, workhome, work"
Company name,Firstname infix infix2 Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180
https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://raku.org

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '2,$s/[^,]*,([^ ]*) [^,]*,/&\1,/;1s/([^,]*,){2}/&FIRSTNAME,/' input_file
COMPANY,FULLNAME,FIRSTNAME,EMAIL,FUNCTION,CITY,INDUSTRY,COMMENT
Company name,Firstname Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
Company name,Firstname infix Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, workhome, work"
Company name,Firstname infix infix2 Lastname,Firstname,firstname.lastname@example.com,Marketing Manager,New York,Health Care,"home, work"
```